# Which version of JBoss AS supports Java EE 6 (specifically JSF2.0)

Tags: jsf, jboss

Which version of JBoss AS supports Java EE 6 (specifically JSF2.0)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None supports Java EE 6 fully yet. This may take some months. But [JSF 2.0](http://javaserverfaces.dev.java.net) in turn is backwards compatible with Servlet 2.5. This means that you can just use JBoss AS 4.2 or newer for this.

Comment: Could you please illustrate a bit more on how to use JSF2.0 in JBoss 4.2?

Comment: Just follow the link, download the binaries, replace both `jsf-api.jar` and `jsf-impl.jar` in JBoss. That should be it.

Comment: I think this answer is obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

AS 6.0 will support Java EE 6. Currently nearing Milestone 2. If you want to try JSF 2, it works fine in the current trunk.

Comment: So there won't be a 5.2 (which had JSF 2.0 + CDI/Weld) actually? I can't find mentions of 5.2 on the JBoss website anymore and http://hudson.jboss.org/hudson/view/JBoss%20AS/job/JBoss-AS-5.x-sun16/ is now disabled. Did JBoss folks decide to go straight for 6.0 or what?

Answer (score 0):

Currently none and could take a while. Only Glassfish is supporting Java EE 6 right now

Answer (score 0):

Following the instructions at http://aaron.ajexperience.com/2010/10/11/jboss-5-with-jsf-2-on-a-per-app-basis/ might let you use JSF 2 on JBoss 5.0.1 GA if you're using Eclipse.